# Python 3: Why does splitlines() on a str results in TypeError? (but not always)

Tags: python, exception

Maybe I'm just too tired to see it, but why does this

```
cmds = '''
AA ''' + ''' BB
'''.splitlines()
```

result in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 3, in <module>
    '''.splitlines()
TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly
```

and this works just fine:

```
cmds = '''
AA ''' + ''' BB
'''
print(cmds.splitlines())
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `splitlines` method is getting called **before** the addition, so this:

```
cmds = '''
AA ''' + ''' BB
'''.splitlines()
```

... is equivalent to this:

```
cmds = ('''
AA ''') + (''' BB
'''.splitlines())
```

... which means you're trying to add a list to a string.

However, in the second case:

```
cmds = '''
AA ''' + ''' BB
'''
print(cmds.splitlines())
```

... you're doing the addition first, and calling `splitlines` on the result.

Answer (score 0):

It is the order in which operations are done. In

```
cmds = '''
AA ''' + ''' BB
'''.splitlines()
```

the `splitlines()` successfully splits the second string

```
''' BB
'''
```

but then it tries to concatenate the result (a list) to the first string

```
'''
AA '''
```

which doesn't make sense. In the second snippet, the concatenations happens first, and then `splitlines` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You first example is splitting the second string before trying to join it to the first string. The second example is joining the two strings first, then splitting it.